# Resolving "No Op-Kernel was registered to support Op" on AMD GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, amd-gpu

```
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(lookback,1)),
    Dense(units=1)
])
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.MSE,optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.fit(trainx,trainy,validation_data=(testx,testy),epochs=20,batch_size=1)
```

model.compile throws error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'CudnnRNN' used by {{node CudnnRNN}} with these attrs: [seed=0, dropout=0, T=DT_FLOAT, input_mode="linear_input", direction="unidirectional", rnn_mode="lstm", seed2=0, is_training=true]
Registered devices: [CPU, GPU]
...
Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[CudnnRNN]]
     [[sequential_2/lstm_6/PartitionedCall]] [Op:__inference_train_function_15994]
```

I have AMD gpu with tensorflow-directml

```
print(tf. __version__)
```

====>2.10.0

```
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

====>[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Note the above code runs perfectly
if I run it on cpu

```
with tf.device('/CPU:0'):
    model.fit(trainx,trainy,validation_data=(testx,testy),epochs=2,batch_size=1,verbose=1)
```

Is there any way to run it on AMD GPU

Comment: Please make sure you have followed all the system requirements to use Directml as mentioned in this [doc](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml-plugin#getting-started) with specified AMD GPU version. Let us know if the issue still persists. You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/tensorflow-directml/issues/134#issuecomment-754263177) to know the DirectML GPU usage in your system.